# Likelihood ratio test for the exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation, log-likelihood

Let $Y$ be a random exponentially distributed variable, with mean $\lambda$. That is, its probability density function is 
$$f(y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ c c } 
             \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{\frac{-y}{\lambda}} & y > 0 \\
             0                                       & y \leq 0
         \end{array} \right.$$

I want to perform a likelihood ratio test to test
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ c c c } 
             H_0 & : & \lambda \leq \lambda_0 \\
             H_1 & : & \lambda >    \lambda_0
\end{array} \right.$$

I derive the likelihood
$$L(\lambda \mid y) = \left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)^n \exp\left(\frac{n\overline{y}}{\lambda}\right)$$
as well as the log-likelihood
$$l(\lambda \mid y) = n \log\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right) - \frac{n\overline{y}}{\lambda}$$

I also know the MLE for $\lambda$,
$$\hat{\lambda} = \overline{y}$$

I have read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942866/likelihood-ratio-of-exponential-distribution) as well as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194181/likelihood-ratio-test-statistic-for-the-exponential-distribution), but just do not understand how to proceed now.

Comment: If you know the procedure, then study the likelihood ratio criterion. For that you need the (restricted) MLE of $\lambda$ when $\lambda\le \lambda_0$ alongwith the unrestricted MLE $\bar y$.

Comment: It is not clear where you are stuck or what you don't understand. So if you add details, maybe there is a better chance of getting a response.